# How to display a custom page from a custom (non crud, custom data) json

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I was able to create a simple admin panel using react-admin 3.x (migated from 2.x) and as data provider the jsonServerProvider.
Now I'd like to have a custom page showing some custom data.

Say I have a json like this:

```
{
  "title":"My custom page",
  "teaser":"This is a custom page showing some stuff",
  "drinks":[{"name":  "coke", "image": "coca-cola.jpg"}, {"name":  "beer", "image": "beer.png"}, {"name":  "coffee", "image":  "cappuccino.jpg"}],
  "additional_stuff": ["some", "more", "stuff"]
}
```

I actually created and endpoint called something like: `/api/drinks/mycustom`

Note, that I already have pages to list, create, edit `drinks`. Now I just wanted a custom page to show them in a different way (not in a CRUD table) and to display extra stuff.

If the endpoint name included in an existing one is a problem, I can place "mycustom" endpoint in a different route.

I'd like to have an entry in the default menu on the left, when clicking it, react-admin should query the resource and populate the page with the json data coming from the endpoint.

I just don't get how to make such a custom page, didn't find a proper example in the documentation and that's why I'm here.

Thanks for providing an example on how to achieve this.

Comment: You can release your page similarly - Dashboard
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#dashboard
then turn it on through the useful menu item

Comment: @MaxAlex thx for the comment, but can you be more specific? Adding a simple dashboard page to specify a different homepage is not what I need. I need a custom page fetching a json and populating the page with that json. If you can provide an answer with some code that can help me reach the goal I can accept it, thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a customRoute in this [way](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes) passing your custom component.

To query the API you don't need a new endpoint if the provided data on the regular ones is sufficient for your needs. Just call the `useGetOne` or `useGetList` [hook](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#specialized-hooks) inside depends on what your custom page shows.

***EDIT:**

In your case let's take the `stats/foo.js` component and assume you want to show another layout for the `trades` resource (swap with any other as you wish):

```
       const Foo = () => {
          const { data, ids, loading, error } = useGetList(
             'trades',
             { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
             { field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }
          );

          if (loading) { return <Loading />; }
          if (error) { return <p>ERROR</p>; }

          return (
            <Card>
              <Title title="Trades Stats" />
              <CardContent>
                <ul>
                 {ids.map(id =>
                    <li key={id}>{data[id].title}</li>
                  )}
                </ul>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>)
        };
```

Now you should be able to access the page on the `/foo` url as this is how it is registered in `customRoutes`.

***EDIT 2**

If you don't want to use the react-admin hooks at all you can do just a regular `fetch` or even get use of react-admin's [fetchUtils](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#adding-custom-headers):

```
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';

const fetchJson = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    // add your own headers here
    // options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
```

and make the following call:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
       fetchJson(baseUrl + '/trades')
          .then(response => {
             return response.json;
          })
          .then(data => {
             setData(data); 
          });
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Card>
      <Title title={data.title} />
      <CardContent>
        <div>{data.teaser}</div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>)
};
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, if you can edit and add more info so to have some code in the answer to help me getting a working solution I can accept it. Check my last commit in my repo here: https://github.com/firepol/crypto-accounting-admin/tree/custom-page I just don't understand where/how to add the hook. I've seen the examples, but don't understand how to use them in my code, in app.js etc. can you help? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Kia I admit that my knowledge of react is too small (and gives me headaches), so please be patient... I tried useGetOne and it gives me errors that it needs redux or so. I tried useGetList but it seems I have to return an array of ids in the json and complains also about `X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response` I really don't need pagination, my json is a simple json as in the question. Isn't there a simple hook to display such a custom json with no pagination, no ids, no x-header needed? Is there a way to console.log the returned json? (The api call works)

Comment: Ok then, check out my second edit if I got it right

Comment: almost there, last little step and it's solved... Please check my code based on your answer: https://gist.github.com/firepol/a49d722ba9310eb98dffde440a28f116
`console.log(data);` inside the `fetchJson` call works as expected. But `console.log(result);` logs a promise with [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object. I'm sorry, I'm not good in JS and even less in react :( how to make this work so that data has its properties as it should, to be rendered via `{data.title}` and `{data.teaser}` in the JSX?

Comment: I don't know why are you dealing with this task but you have way too little knowledge over the basics of js promises/async operations and react lifecycle methods ... if you don't take your time to learn them you will constantly hit issues like this one. I have edited my second half of the answer but I can't help you from now on, your question is already answered quite some time ago so please accept the answer.

Comment: I had to edit (edit must be approved by trusted community members...) your answer to make it look more like this one: https://dev.to/nicomartin/the-right-way-to-fetch-data-with-react-hooks-48gc

`React.useState();` should be: `React.useState([]);` and `React.useEffect(() => {...});` should be `React.useEffect(() => {...}, []);` else I was getting errors (data.title undefined), even with a JSX without variables it was behaving weirldy, calling my endpoint infinite times :)

Thanks for your time, you asked why I'm dealing with this "task". Well it's a side project to learn a bit of react ;)

Comment: Yeah, I missed those arrays in the hurry, I was coding directly in the SO editor. React is awesome and realtively easy, keep up experimenting but also take your time to go through the docs and tutorials of plain React. Then react-admin will start to make much more sense. Good luck!